# Javascript timezone solution needed(taking into account the actual difference in UTC timestamps)

Tags: javascript, mysql, datetime

I have unix timestamps from time zone X which is not known,

the current timestamp(`now()`) in TZ X is known `1275143019`,

how to approach a javascript function so that it can generate the datetime in the users current TZ in the format `2010-05-29 15:32:35` ?

**UPDATE**

I'm not a unix timestamp expert,if unix timestamp is always the same in different TZ,

then I have to change the question a little,so that the current datetime in TZ X is known(like `2010-05-29 22:32:28`),and the other datetime is also in this format,how to convert them to the user's TZ based on the difference between `now()` ?

**UPDATE**

Something strange from MySQL:

On server:

```
mysql> select now();
+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2010-05-29 18:34:30 | 
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
+------------------+
| UNIX_TIMESTAMP() |
+------------------+
|       1275143674 | 
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

On local:

```
mysql> select now();
+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2010-05-29 22:41:30 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
+------------------+
| UNIX_TIMESTAMP() |
+------------------+
|       1275144091 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why the difference between `now()` (`2010-05-29 22:41:30-2010-05-29 18:34:30=6hours`) and `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` (`1275144091 - 1275143674 = 417seconds`) is not the same ?

Comment: unix timespamp is always in UTC

Comment: You've asked **500 questions** and only accepted answers on **half** of them?!?

Comment: Don't hurry,this question is far from being solved yet.

Comment: If the database server is a separate machine, then it's probably the case that the clocks are not correctly synchronized.

Comment: Do you mean that `select UNIX_TIMESTAMP();` should be the same on `server` and `local` even though they're in different TZ?

Comment: Yes, they should, because the Unix/Linux timestamp is always relative to a particular point in time (1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 UTC). If they're not, then one of the machines, or possibly both of them, have a bad clock setting.

Comment: Then my question should be like the first update above.

Comment: At this very moment I am in US Central Time (like Chicago), and my Unix timestamp is 1275145010

Comment: I've answered your question: convert your local time to UTC and then use the "setUTC" methods on a Javascript "Date" object.

Comment: `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` is supposed to be UTC, so I don't see what you mean by "convert your local time to UTC " ?

Comment: Read my answer!  It already includes everything you need to know. If you have a unix timestamp value, just multiply it by 1000 and pass it in as the argument to `new Date(utc * 1000)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you instantiate a Date object, you can pass in a Unix-style "milliseconds since the epoch" time value:

```
var date = new Date(milliseconds);
```

That time value is interpreted as UTC. When you call toString on that date object, or use the getters for hour/minute/second, you get values in the local timezone at the client.

As noted by @vava in a comment, the milliseconds or seconds current time value you get back from Unix/Linux is *always* UTC to begin with, so your server can drop that value into a page and when it executes on the client, the right thing will happen.

*edit* — If you need to convert from local time on the server to local time at the client, you really need to get your server time in UTC, or at least know the UTC offset. From year/month/day hour/minute/second values you can set up a Javascript date with the "setUTCFoo" functions (where "Foo" if "FullYear", "Month", "Date", "Hour", "Minute", "Seconds", "Milliseconds").

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: I need to take into account the difference of UTC of server/client time,even though it may be caused by clock or whatever.

Comment: Are you serious that matters?

Comment: Well, for example, `22:41:30 - 18:34:30' is **not** a "7 hour" difference. It's a difference of 4 hours and 7 minutes.  If your machines were simply in different time zones, then the time difference would be an even number of hours and no extra minutes.

Comment: Ok, I agree this may be a clock problem, but can be fixed if I can get current timestamp in javascript.

Comment: The current value comparable to UNIX_TIMESTAMP in Javascript is `var timestamp = new Date().getTime()` - that's like a "Unix" timestamp multiplied by 1000.

Comment: Almost there ! The final step is how to convert the datetime to format of `2010-05-29 23:39:02` after `var d = new Date(1275146345*1000);` ?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the select now(); commands is because of the timezone difference.
The select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(); should be always the same on any two machines.

Why is then the 417 seconds differene? It is simple:

> 417 seconds ~= 7 minutes
>
> 22:41:30 - 18:34:30 = 7 minutes

Synchronize the clocks and the unix timestamps will be the same.

Comment: 22:41:30 - 18:34:30 = 7 **hours** ,not **minutes**

Comment: Also,I've tried several different machines,their results of `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` are all different,so I can't rely on this UTC timestamp.

Comment: If you can't rely on the timestamp, then none of this makes any sense at all. Fix your clocks.  There's no API to tell you how wrong your clock is; it makes no sense.

Comment: But as you have seens in my post,there is difference in UTC timestamp practically, do you want me to just ignore it ?

Comment: If the clocks on your servers are wrong, you have to fix them. Otherwise there's no way to know what the real UTC time is. That seems so obvious. All the clocks on my network return the same time, to within a couple milliseconds of each other, because my machines (like any well-managed machine) use NTP to keep synchronized.

Comment: That's only a matter of start point, say the difference is fixed. The problem exists, no complain, but fix. For your "All the clocks",I'd guess they're in the same TZ,which of course don't need to worry about the TZ problem.

Comment: If the difference is fixed (still makes no sense, but whatever) then we're talking about a simple subtraction problem. Just add/subtract the offset as appropriate. However the fact remains that if your servers are returning different time values, then the clocks are wrong.